# Querying Quickbooks with a service account

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a need to run periodic batch queries against Quickbooks Online. Is there a way to accomplish this with a service account which does not require user interaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Quickbooks online data in my webapp without the user logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424785/how-to-get-quickbooks-online-data-in-my-webapp-without-the-user-logging-in)

Comment: Read the post above ^^^.  It covers EXACTLY what you're asking. TLDR: You misunderstand how OAuth works.

Comment: The answer is indeed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424785/how-to-get-quickbooks-online-data-in-my-webapp-without-the-user-logging-in Thanks Keith